# Multiple HTTPRequests in sequence that rely on each other

Tags: vb.net, vbscript

I'm converting a VBScript to VB.Net, and I'm hung up on handling web requests.

I've read that I don't need the MSXML2.XMLHTTP object, but it seems way more complicated in VB.Net to do a webrequest.

VBScript source (actual URLs and post string not given):

```
Set oXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

    'Submit web requests
    oXMLHTTP.Open "GET", sLoginURL, False
    oXMLHTTP.Send

    oXMLHTTP.Open "POST", sResultsURL, False
    oXMLHTTP.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    oXMLHTTP.Send sFormData

    oXMLHTTP.Open "GET", sResultsHandlerURL, False
    oXMLHTTP.Send

    msgbox(oXMLHTTP.ResponseText)
```

So this works, and returns a nice JSON string with the results.  A few things to note:

- First request 'logs you in'.  No idea how this works, just noticed in Fiddler that when you go to this site, it redirects you to that URL, then you hop back.  It's somehow tied in with my companies single-sign on.  script doesn't work without it though
- Second request actually runs a search
- Third request pulls results from a different URL as a JSON string, which is what I ultimately want.
- The actual 'site' consists of a few frames.  One frame is the webform to build the second request.  Another frame pulls/displays the results in a nice format using the JSON from the third request.

I've tried using the function here: http://www.808.dk/?code-vbnet-httpwebrequest to run these requests in sequence, but it doesn't work.  I think it's because it's making a new HTTPRequest each time the function is called.

I think it has something to do with the cookies to, but not clear how that works in vb.net either.

TL;DR.  How to convert above script into vb.net

P.S. Why is it so much more complicated in VB.Net?  I would have thought it would be easier haha.

Comment: You need to set a CookieContainer on the first request, then use the SAME instance of the CookieContainer when making the second request. [Here](http://contrivedexample.com/2015/03/08/authenticating-to-asp-net-membership-provider-programmatically/) is an example that demonstrates a similar thing in C#. Apologies for the formatting, it didn't come over from my previous blog completely intact.

Comment: That did the trick, modified the function in my link to pass ByRef a cookie container and it worked.  Posted final solution below.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make it work with Crowcoder's advice on my post.  I modified the function from the link in my post as follows:

```
Function WRequest(URL As String, method As String, POSTdata As String, ByRef cookieJar As CookieContainer) As String
    Dim responseData As String = ""
    Try

        Dim hwrequest As Net.HttpWebRequest = Net.WebRequest.Create(URL)
        hwrequest.CookieContainer = cookieJar
        hwrequest.Accept = "*/*"
        hwrequest.AllowAutoRedirect = True
        hwrequest.UserAgent = "http_requester/0.1"
        hwrequest.Timeout = 60000
        hwrequest.Method = method
        If hwrequest.Method = "POST" Then
            hwrequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            Dim encoding As New ASCIIEncoding() 'Use UTF8Encoding for XML requests
            Dim postByteArray() As Byte = encoding.GetBytes(POSTdata)
            hwrequest.ContentLength = postByteArray.Length
            Dim postStream As IO.Stream = hwrequest.GetRequestStream()
            postStream.Write(postByteArray, 0, postByteArray.Length)
            postStream.Close()
        End If
        Dim hwresponse As Net.HttpWebResponse = hwrequest.GetResponse()
        If hwresponse.StatusCode = Net.HttpStatusCode.OK Then
            Dim responseStream As IO.StreamReader = _
              New IO.StreamReader(hwresponse.GetResponseStream())
            responseData = responseStream.ReadToEnd()
        End If
        hwresponse.Close()
    Catch e As Exception
        responseData = "An error occurred: " & e.Message
    End Try
    Return responseData
End Function
```

Then called it as follows:

```
Dim cookieJar As New CookieContainer

WRequest(sLoginURL, "GET", "", cookieJar)
WRequest(sResultsURL, "POST", postString, cookieJar)
Debug.Print(WRequest(sResultsHandlerURL, "GET", "", cookieJar))
```

Way more complicated than the VBS haha, but it works!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [WebClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx) class in this instance.  It handles much of the code from the example you cited as it uses the WebRequest Class.

```
    Dim objWebClient As New WebClient()

    objWebClient.DownloadString(sLoginUrl)

    objWebClient.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    objWebClient.UploadString(sResultsURL, "POST", sFormData)

    objWebClient.DownloadString(sResultsHandlerURL)
```

Comment: No luck.  Seems like it should work, but doesn't.  Must be something with how the cookies are handled.  I followed Crowcoder's suggestion from above and it worked.  Posted full solution below.